# How do I perform a dynamic WHERE clause in QuestDB?

Tags: sql, questdb

I'm looking to create a dynamic `WHERE` clause in QuestDB for something like [the following example SQL](https://mitchelsellers.com/blog/article/creating-dynamic-where-clauses-with-sql):

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnA VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @ColumnB VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM TestData
WHERE 1=1'

IF(@ColumnA IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
               AND ColumnA = ''' + @ColumnA + ''''
END

IF(@ColumnB IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
                AND ColumnB = ''' + @ColumnB + ''''
END

EXEC(@SQL)
```

What's the nicest way to do this? I can't find guidance in the [WHERE keyword documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you're trying to achieve, but what might be useful is using `coalesce()` which was [added in release 5.0.6.1](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/releases/tag/5.0.6.1). The function is designed to work like the Postgres `COALESCE` keyword and returns the first non-null argument. There are ways that this could be included in your statement, but it's useful if you want to set a default value for a column if it returns null:

```sql
SELECT
    coalesce(ColumnA, 0.12) as column_a_not_null
    coalesce(ColumnB, 2.34) as column_b_not_null
FROM TestData
```

if you want to omit rows where **both columns** are null, you can use:

```sql
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM TestData
WHERE ColumnA != null OR ColumnB != null
```

and if you want to omit rows where **null is in any column**, you could use

```sql
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM TestData
WHERE ColumnA != null AND ColumnB != null
```

If you want to see more examples on coalesce(), you can have a look at the [conditional functions documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/conditional).